# How do I load a gzip-compressed csv file in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The file names don't end with `.gz` and I cannot change them back as they are shared with other programs.

`file1.log.gz.processed` is simply a `csv` file. But how do I read it in `pyspark`, preferably in `pyspark.sql`?

I tried to specify the format and compression but couldn't find the correct key/value. E.g.,

`sqlContext.load(fn, format='gz')`

didn't work. Although Spark could deal with `gz` files it seems to determine the codec from file names. E.g.,

`sc.textFile(fn)`

would work if the file ends with `.gz` but not in my case.

How do I instruct Spark to use the correct codec? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use .load that way, as it's [deprecated](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext) (since version 1.4.0). You should use `read.format(source).schema(schema).options(options).load()`.

```
sql_context.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.options(
  header=... # e.g., "true"
  inferSchema=...)
.load(file_path + ".gz")
```

Comment: That `options` is exactly what I'm looking for. Could you please provide the link to its full specification (params and values)? Thank you.

Comment: It still gives uncompressed data: ```Row(C0=u'\x1f\ufffd\x08\x00\ufffd\ufffdcV\x00\x03\ufffdSMO\ufffd0\x14\ufffd\ufffd?\ufffd[\x12\ufffd\ufffdo\ufffd\x08\tJ\x0b\ufffd\ufffdPi\x0f=U\ufffd\ufffd\u01bbK\x12\x12/\ufffdh\x7f<\ufffd')```

Comment: I have to confirm that the above solution DOESN'T work as long as the file name doesn't end with '.gz'... really annoying.

Comment: That's ridiculous, I agree. I must say I never had the same issue (as files are normally .gzip ended), but I though that specifying the codec would help. What if you use .textFile()

Comment: Please, try to add the .gzip extension to your file before reading (ridiculous, though)

Comment: Seems changing the file names is the only way to go? Not ideal, but at least a solution without too much pain. Excuse me, I need to buy a few engineers coffees now :)

Comment: Could you just create a soft (i.e. symbolic) link to the original files? That way you don't have to change filenames, just add another reference to the original ones.

Comment: Unfortunately files are in S3.